# Make last of stacked div's inside header/footer 100% height of the rest

Tags: css, html

Currently trying to find a clean solution for achieving the following layout for a sidebar like this

- Header
- Section 1 that updates it's (dynamic) height aligned to the content
- Section 2 that takes the rest of the height with content that needs to scroll if it doesn't fit anymore
- Footer

How to make Section 2 taking the remaining space between Section 1 and the footer as nothing I tried makes it happen?

```
#data_section {
    /*Section 2*/
    position: relative;
    background: red;

    /* This needs to be 100% of the 'reset' excluding the footer */
    /*height: 100%;*/

    /* he content needs to scroll if it outgrows the height */
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}
```

Is there a CSS only solution for this kind of layout that works on >= IE9 and current FF, Chrome, Safari versions?

As it is part of a JavaScript centric application nothing speaks against using JS to calculate the dimensions. But as I always have a hard time when it comes to CSS and it's capabilities it would be nice to see if there's a "clean way" in doing by CSS only.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/CC7YZ/) a fiddle with the barebones layout without getting Section 2 to do what it should.

Comment: please show the css and html without comments......can you please provide the markup???

Comment: Is using the same HTML structure important to you? Can you not modify it? I'd actually absolutely position the footer in the data_wrapper section towards the bottom while the data_wrapper itself will be absolutely positioned to touch the bottom.

Comment: @Chandranshu The structure is not important. The fiddle is just my first draft where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Mayank The current markup is shown in the linked Fiddle. Any issues with that?

Comment: checked it...my bad!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `display:table;` and `display: table-row`. The nifty thing with these display types is that the rows will both try to fill the entire table as well as fitting the content inside. Because of this, you can set `height: 0;` to the rows that you want to merely fit the content, and let section 2 just fill the rest.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CC7YZ/1/)

Comment: That looks good. Never really used CSS tables. But good to see that it makes this kind of em quite easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no content as per you Fiddle, my suggestion would be to add :
`padding-bottom : 90%; // adjust the value to your need` 
to your css in `#data_section`, as this will mark up the color in entire remaining area without affecting the footer!